# Why can't I delete an MX Record from my domain provider?

Tags: domain

I'm doing some email redirection tests with my domain. I tried several configurations, but now the mx record refuses to be removed from the domain provider.

Is this a provider bug or there is some reason why the MX Record can't be deleted ? I don't receive any error messages. The MX record simply can't be deleted. I can alter the address but can't remove it.

I got only 4 records:

```
www 173.214.161.46     A   10
*   173.214.161.46     A   10
@   173.214.161.46     A   10
@   aspmx.l.google.com MX  1
```

Why can't I delete the MX line ?

I use a brasilian provider called `e-dominios.com.br`

Comment: Don’t forget to wait out TTL....

Comment: I waited. Didn't work either after 2 days.

Comment: I have plenty of domains with no MX record, so it’s not required.  You need to contact whatever provider is providing DNS, they appear to have made it impossible to delete.

Comment: I have 3 other domains in the same provider with no MX record. But after I put it in, it sticks. I already contacted support. The purpose of the question was to determine if this is a bug of the web interface or if I there was some other reason why this is happening.

Comment: My guess is the provider made it hard to do on purpose, so that they don’t have to deal with people that don’t know what an MX record is, and deleted because they were following instructions that say “delete any existing records and simply add this A or CNAME”, then the next thing is “help, my emails broken”

Comment: Maybe, but I'm a developer and I need to do tests. The support has just emailed me offering to make any configurations I need and I answered them I what I want is the web interface working to do theses tests. That makes your hypotesis very likely. Let's see what they answer